# How Linux decides what `malloc` to use?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I know how to replace `malloc` with `LD_PRELOAD`; library that preloaded gets priority, so if we preload `jemalloc`, executable gets its `malloc` version.
However, when we build application with `-ljemalloc`, we also link it against `glibc`. How Linux knows that it has to use `jemalloc` `malloc` and not `glibc` one? What if I will link both `jemalloc` and `tcmalloc`, we'll have 3 `malloc` now, what and why Linux (or may be the linker, I am not sure) will select?

Comment: The first one it sees. Now to understand in what order it looks ;-)

Comment: Do you include `glibc` in your definition of linux? Or `ld.so`? Linux can be fuzzily defined from time to time.

Comment: Well, about definition of Linux in this question, actually it means: library selection is made at linking time (by linker) or at run time (by "Linux"); for example, if `libjemalloc` is absent, will the software automatically downgrade to another `malloc` implementation in another `so` linked to software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the order of libraries being loaded by running:

`strace -ff -s 999 YOUR_BINARY 2>&1 | grep -e 'library1' -e 'library2'`

The order should match the output from `ldd YOUR_BINARY`.

And yes, as already noted, the first library will get priority.

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting. Some OSes warn you about replicated symbols at link time (AIX, IIRC). Linux does not.

Something similar happens when instrumenting MPI apps through the PMPI interface. In this case the order is important. If the instrumentation tool comes after the MPI library, then the interposition does not work. So I'd think than in your case would be the same. The linker will choose by their given order.

Comment: Some *linkers* will warn you. It doesn't have anything to do with the operating system.

Comment: Ah! I always related the linker to the OS but, of course, we may have different linkers. Thank you for the clarification.